# checking input in php for array values

Tags: php, input

I'm checking all input in php in both POST and GET and i'm turning them into html entities before anything else in my application.

problem is though, when i have multiple inputs of the same name (eg. multiple checkboxes ). my input checker nulls the array.

i want to check the POST and GET arrays and i want to check all the multiple inputs of the same name (ie. arrays ) within them.

can anyone suggest a piece of code to me ?

```
 // Input validation
 $_GET = array_map("input_check",$_GET);
 $_POST = array_map("input_check",$_POST);

 // Check input strings
 function input_check($arr)
 {

     return htmlentities($arr,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'); 

 }
```

Comment: Not sure if you've seen my updated answer but it's pretty important to avoid `array_map()`

Answer (score 1):

recursion! Welcome to the Welcome to the to the world of recursion!

`array_map()` will cause you to lose keys so let the function handle everything.

You will need to check and account for arrays:

```
// Input validation
$_GET = input_check($_GET);
$_POST = input_check($_POST);

// Check input strings
function input_check($arr)
{
    if(is_array($arr))
    {
        // Since this value is an array we need to apply this
        // function to each element inside the array and maintain
        // the original keys
        foreach($arr as $k=>$v)
        {
            $arr[$k] = input_check($v);
        }
    }
    elseif(is_string($arr))
    {
        $arr = htmlentities($arr,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8');
    }
    return $arr;
}
```